# XPATH - how to grab data from html in flat structure?

Tags: xpath

Once again I am completely beaten by XPATH. I can only grab this div it seems and nothing else:

```
.//span[@class='noQuotes']
```

This gives me the title. I have tried every other possibility but cannot grab a single item from this loop. I have tried using: `//div[@class='wrap']` for my context and this seems to loop but won't grab these items:

```
<div class="entry">
    <p class="partial_entry">
        <span class="ratingDate relativeDate"
```

I have tried `.//div[@class='entry']`, `./div[@class='entry']`, `/div[@class='entry']` plus tried the p class as well but cannot grab one bit of the text. Can anyone please help me with this or tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="quote">
        <a href="/example" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('')" id="rn186515977">&#x201c;<span class='noQuotes'>Average</span>&#x201d;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rating reviewItemInline">
        <span class="rate sprite-rating_s rating_s">
            <img class="sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s30" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="3 of 5 stars" content="3.0">
        </span>
        <span class="ratingDate relativeDate" title='December 2, 2013'>Reviewed yesterday
            <span class="new">NEW</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <p class="partial_entry">
        Looks better in pictures, like the balcony and the bed but bit on the small side plus a 150-250 deposit is huge! 
        Close to canary wharf underground and has decent food places/shopping close by! Beautiful scenery and views from the balcony
        Price is very good, but have stayed in better for the price! asked for wifi code and was told...
            <span class="partnerRvw">
                <span class="example_1" onclick="example">
                More </span>
                <img class="textArrow_more sprite-text_arrow_dropdown_blu" src="http://dddd.gif" alt="" width="10" height="11">
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="helpfulq186515977_collapsed" class="helpful ">
            <span class="isHelpful"><strong>Was this review helpful?</strong></span>
            <span class="tgt_helpfulq186515977 rndBtn rndBtnGreen rndBtnSmall" onclick="ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(5034); ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.helpfulVoteHandlerOb', event, this, 'LeJIVqd4EVIpECri1qgqWQQoqnQQeVsSVuqHyUv3mmvqHMX3ookXqHxfqHqnEJtVEQQoqnQQwcJnVQQoqnQQfJCJEgQQoqnQQxdGJETqHRiCMiCQQoqnQQzsCycJCMxiGIac6XoXmqoTpcUv3oUoAkk0tEn1Uv3oUoAkk0zH1Uv3mmv0pSM1fqnm3AzsKKbXvvmmvokfoovUqnzsxMA3Xzszszsv0EJIVqiJcpV1U');; ta.trackEventOnPage('helpful_vote_button', 'Yes')">Yes</span>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap reportProblem">
            <span id="ReportIAP_186515977" class="problem collapsed taLnk" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Reviews', 'report_problem', 'click'); ta.call('ta.overlays.Factory.iapFlyout', event, this, {voteContentType:'USERREVIEW', contentId: '186515977'})" onmouseover="ta.trackEventOnPage('Reviews', 'report_problem', 'hover_over_flag'); this.onmouseover=null">
                <span class="hidden ulBlueLinks">Problem with this review?</span>
                <img id='lazyload_483652333_2' height='14' alt='' width='13'/>
            </span>
    </div> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is seems unclear to me. What is your context? what you want to get by XPATH?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you have to missing closing tags on `<img>` elements, the `//div[@class='entry']` XPath expression works just fine. Give it a try yourself in http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. I second @NavinRawat: What is your context and what are you trying to get?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry if this is not so clear. I am trying to get the information in this div: <p class="partial_entry"> (the main textual content) and also the date here: title='December 2, 2013' and this rating: content="3.0">. I am using a context that wraps around each loop of the webpage, in this case that is: //div[@class='wrap']